# How do I center lines of multiline label in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below div which contains a span element. What I am trying to accomplish is have the text "STATUS" centered over "FAILED UPLOAD".

```css
.entity-form-status {
  font-size: 8pt;
  color: #FFFFFFF;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8 column" align="right">
  <span class="entity-form-status">
     STATUS<br>[FAILED UPLOAD]
   </span>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather straight-forward, what's the issue?

```css
.entity-form-status {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8 column" align="right">
  <span class="entity-form-status">
     STATUS<br>[FAILED UPLOAD]
   </span>
</div>
```